# Can I use my own sound files instead of the default ones?

Tags: terraria

After playing Terraria for a little while, I have started to find the default sounds for when a player takes damage a little annoying and I'm looking for a way to use my own sound files instead of the default ones provided with the game.

I have seen that it is possible to change to an already existing sound in the Terraria sound folder ([here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1903130)), but I am looking to use my own sounds so this doesn't exactly fit what I'm looking for.

I guess I need to know a couple of things in order to be able to do this:

- What format should the sound files be in?
- What should I use to convert the files to the .xnb format?

Comment: I am assuming that this is allowed according to the Terraria [Terms of Use](http://www.terraria.org/terms.html) since it should not require any reverse engineering to be able to do this.

Comment: I don't think those terms even apply to Terraria at all, since they're the "*Web Site* Terms and Conditions" and concern "materials [...] on Terraria's web site". If you buy Terraria from Steam, you never interact with http://www.terraria.org/ at all.

Comment: @lunboks Ah yes, that looks to be the case. I can't seem to find a link to the terms for the game itself, but I guess the assumption still stands.

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert your sound files into XNB format, the packaged format Microsoft XNA uses for binary files. The best guide I've found is designed for creating [custom music soundtracks](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/how-to-custom-soundtracks.21951/), but the steps are the same for replacing sound effects.

You just need to convert your sounds using XACT and replace the existing sounds with your new ones. The game uses the filename to determine which sound to play for each event, so make sure those stay the same.